# oracle sql developer first time user

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new to plsql and trying to use oracle sql developer, I try to run a simple procedure with dbms output line and i get the following error,

> ora-00904

, the code is

```
create or replace PROCEDURE proc_101 IS
    v_string_tx   VARCHAR2(256) := 'Hello World';
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(v_string_tx);
END;
```

whether i click the run(green colour) or debug(red colour) i get the same error.

You can see from the above code, procedure doesn't access any objects but still i get the same error.

Comment: Please provide relevant code

Comment: create or replace PROCEDURE EMP_NAME 
(
  PARAM1 IN NUMBER 
) AS 
rec emp%rowtype;
BEGIN
  select * into rec from emp where EMPNO=PARAM1;
END EMP_NAME;

Comment: No, please edit your question instead of posting it as a comment

Comment: add this line dbms_output.put_line(rec.ename); before end;

Comment: [There's nothing wrong with your posted procedure](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7ab59f98d106fd545dda41562303473f). However, your comment doesn't match up with the posted code, which means you've not checked whether it is actually a minimal demonstration of your problem.

Comment: ORA-00904 is "invalid identifier". It seems likely you're accessing an object which doesn't exist.... your procedure doesn't access a table.

Comment: please upload a screenshot of your sql developer editor - it should have ALL the code, and the error message as reported in your question/title

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure is fine.  You may not have permissions to be able to Create a Procedure.  If this is the case test your procedure/code without actually Creating it in the Database first.  For example, when I'm testing code in my Production database my oracle user cannot Create Procedures, Packages, Tables etc... And so I test my Procedures within my Own PL/SQL Blocks.  When the code is good to go I can get a database administrator to Create the Procedures and/or Packages for me.

#### The below screenshot is code that simply tests the Procedure:

[image]

#### The below screenshot is code that does much more and tests the Procedure from within a PL/SQL Block

> For more advanced situations this allows you to do so much more as you can create all sorts of Procedures/Functions and/or Cursors and test them immediately without needing to CREATE these objects in your Oracle Database.
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that there's some other code in the worksheet which raises that error, not just the `CREATE PROCEDURE` you posted. For example, something like this SQL*Plus example (just to show what's going on - you'd get the same result in SQL Developer):

```
SQL> select pixie from dual;
select pixie from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "PIXIE": invalid identifier


SQL>
SQL> create or replace PROCEDURE proc_101 IS
  2      v_string_tx   VARCHAR2(256) := 'Hello World';
  3  BEGIN
  4      dbms_output.put_line(v_string_tx);
  5  END;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

See? The first part raised ORA-00904 as there's no PIXIE column in DUAL, while the procedure is created correctly.

So - remove code which fails and everything should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Check with your DBA to make sure the dbms_output package has been installed on your database, and that you have permissions on it.